# How to configure mocha to support ES6 with node v13 and bable v6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

How to configure test setup with mocha to support es6 with babel 6?

I tried to configure with --require option with mocha as [as mentioned here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation#what-should-i-use-instead-then) but it does not resolve my problem

I have also tried with --compiler option but it does not support with mocha v7

Node v13.13.0

Babel v6.26

mocha v7.1.1

```
> mocha './test/**/*.js' --require babel-core/register

import module from '../models/module';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Module is a .js files

babelConfig.babelrc file contains

```
{ 
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

pakcage.json configrations of scripts section:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js --exec babel-node --presets env",
    "release": "npm run clean && npm run build && npm run serve",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist",
    "build": "babel . -s -D -d dist --presets env --ignore node_modules",
    "serve": "node dist/server.js",
    "test": "mocha './test/**/*.js' --require babel-core/register"
  }
```